# unity photon networking mousedown function not working (beginner)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am new to photon and I am trying to detect when the mouse is clicked to simulate recoil and send a raycast. After I noticed it wasnt working, I used a debug function to see if the onmousedown function was working
but it did not
here is the code for my player

```
void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("mousedown");
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.transform.position, Camera.transform.forward, out hit))
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are raycadting anyways, I would reccomend using the bool variable: Input.GetKeyDown or Input.GetKey.

```
void Update()
{
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)
  {
    //Do your thing like raycast
  }
}
```

If you really want to use OnMouseDown, try [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/486847/onmousedown-doesnt-work-1.html).